# Dependency chain analysis

Tags: performance, assembly, x86, cpu-architecture, micro-optimization

From [Agner Fog's "Optimizing Assembly" guide](http://agner.org/optimize/), Section 12.7: a loop example.  One of the paragraphs discussing the example code:

> [...] Analysis for Pentium M: ... 13 uops at 3 per clock = one iteration per 4.33c retirement time.
>
> There is a dependency chain in the loop. The latencies are: 2 for
>   memory read, 5 for multiplication, 3 for subtraction, and 3 for memory
>   write, which totals 13 clock cycles. This is three times as much as
>   the retirement time but it is not a loop-carried dependence because
>   the results from each iteration are saved to memory and not reused in
>   the next iteration. The out-of-order execution mechanism and
>   pipelining makes it possible that each calculation can start before
>   the preceding calculation is finished. The only loop-carried
>   dependency chain is `add eax,16` which has a latency of only 1.

```
## Example 12.6b.  DAXPY algorithm, 32-bit mode
[...]   ; not shown: initialize some regs before the loop
L1:
    movapd xmm1, [esi+eax]   ; X[i], X[i+1]
    mulpd  xmm1, xmm2        ; X[i] * DA, X[i+1] * DA
    movapd xmm0, [edi+eax]   ; Y[i], Y[i+1]
    subpd  xmm0, xmm1        ; Y[i]-X[i]*DA, Y[i+1]-X[i+1]*DA
    movapd [edi+eax], xmm0   ; Store result
    add eax, 16              ; Add size of two elements to index
    cmp eax, ecx             ; Compare with n*8
    jl L1                    ; Loop back
```

I cannot understand why the dependency chain doesn't increase a whole throughput.  I know that it is only important to find the worst bottleneck.  The worst bottleneck identified before considering dependency chains was fused-domain uop throughput, at 4.33 cycles per iteration.  I cannot understand why the dependency chain isn't a bigger bottleneck than that.

1. I see that the author explains that it is connected with out-of-order execution and pipelining but I cannot see it. I mean, though, only multiplication causes latency 5 cycles so only this value is greater than 4 cycle.
2. I also cannot understand why the author doesn't care about the dependency here:
   `add eax, 16 -> cmp eax, ecx -> jl L1`
   After all, addition must be executed before `cmp` and `cmp` must be executed before `jl`.

---

PS: later paragraphs identify the biggest bottleneck for Pentium M as decode, limiting it to one iteration per 6c, because 128b vector ops decode to two uops each.  See Agner Fog's guide for the rest of the analysis, and analysis + tuning for Core2, FMA4 Bulldozer, and Sandybridge.

Comment: The compare/branch pair would be predicted so it doesn't really count. Apart from that I'm not sure what you're asking

Comment: Can you please link Agner's document and state what section and example you are referencing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. the mul isn't part of a **loop-carried** dependency chain, so there can be `mulpd` insns from multiple iterations in flight at once.  The latency of a single instruction isn't the issue here at all, it's the dependency *chain*.  Each iteration has a *separate* 13c dependency chain of load, mulpd, subpd, store.  Out-of-order execution is what allows uops from multiple iterations to be in flight at once.
2. The `cmp` / `jl` in each iteration depend on the `add` from that iteration, but the `add` in the next iteration doesn't depend on the `cmp`.  Speculative execution and branch prediction mean that control dependencies (conditional branches and indirect jumps/calls) are *not* part of data dependency chains.  This is why instructions from one iteration can start running before the `jl` from the preceding iteration retires.

   By comparison, `cmov` *is* a data dependency instead of a control dependency, so branchless loops tend to have loop-carried dependency chains.  This tends to be slower than branching if the branch predicts well.

   Each loop iteration has a separate `cmp`/`jl` dependency chain, just like the FP dependency chain.

---

> I cannot understand why dependency chain doesn't increase a whole throughput.

I have no idea what this sentence means.  I think I was able to figure out all your other mixed up words and phrasing.  (e.g. "chain dependency" instead of "dependency chain".)  Have a look at my edits to your question; some of them might help your understanding, too.

Comment: Thanks :). To first your point: Ok, it is clear that multiple iterations can be in flight at once. But, When It comes to only ONE iteration, particualar iteration. Why latency of mulpd ( 5 cycles) doesn't matter? After all, `subpd xmm0, xmm1` must be followed by `mulpd xmm1, xmm2` ( in one dependency chain for one iteration). Sorry for my English, I know that it can be problematic.

2. Agner Fog says that `add eax, 16` is loop-carried and it costs 1 cycle (latency).

Comment: @Gilgamesz: 2. That's correct.  `add` -> `add` is the loop-carried dependency chain, not `add -> cmp -> jl -> add`.

Comment: re: first point: Can you be more specific about why you think it *does* matter?  We're calculating throughput, *not* the latency of a single iteration.  As long as the out-of-order insn scheduler and ReOrder Buffer are big enough to expose the parallelism between iterations, latency of the dep chain within an iteration is irrelevant.  (A really long dep chain would require a big scheduler and ROB).  Latency of any specific instructions in that dep chain is even less relevant.

Comment: Ok, @Peter Cordes it makes a sense. Thank you very much.  :)