# Latency of short loop

Tags: performance, assembly, optimization, x86, micro-optimization

I'm trying to understand why some simple loops run at the speeds they do

**First case:**

```
L1:
    add rax, rcx  # (1)
    add rcx, 1    # (2)
    cmp rcx, 4096 # (3)
    jl L1
```

And according to [IACA](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-architecture-code-analyzer), throughput is 1 cycle and bottleneck are ports 1,0,5.
I don't understand why it is 1 cylce. After all we have a two loop-carried dependencies:

```
(1) -> (1) ( Latancy is 1) 
(2) -> (2), (2) -> (1), (2) -> (3) (Latency is 1 + 1 + 1).
```

And this latancy is loop-carried so it should make slower our iteration.

```
Throughput Analysis Report
--------------------------
Block Throughput: 1.00 Cycles       Throughput Bottleneck: Port0, Port1, Port5

Port Binding In Cycles Per Iteration:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Port  |  0   -  DV  |  1   |  2   -  D   |  3   -  D   |  4   |  5   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cycles | 1.0    0.0  | 1.0  | 0.0    0.0  | 0.0    0.0  | 0.0  | 1.0  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------


| Num Of |              Ports pressure in cycles               |    |
|  Uops  |  0  - DV  |  1  |  2  -  D  |  3  -  D  |  4  |  5  |    |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1    | 1.0       |     |           |           |     |     | CP | add rax, rcx
|   1    |           | 1.0 |           |           |     |     | CP | add rcx, 0x1
|   1    |           |     |           |           |     | 1.0 | CP | cmp rcx, 0x1000
|   0F   |           |     |           |           |     |     |    | jl 0xfffffffffffffff2
Total Num Of Uops: 3
```

---

**Second Case**:

```
L1:    
    add rax, rcx
    add rcx, 1
    add rbx, rcx
    cmp rcx, 4096
    jl L1
```

---

```
Block Throughput: 1.65 Cycles       Throughput Bottleneck: InterIteration

Port Binding In Cycles Per Iteration:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Port  |  0   -  DV  |  1   |  2   -  D   |  3   -  D   |  4   |  5   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cycles | 1.4    0.0  | 1.4  | 0.0    0.0  | 0.0    0.0  | 0.0  | 1.3  |


| Num Of |              Ports pressure in cycles               |    |
|  Uops  |  0  - DV  |  1  |  2  -  D  |  3  -  D  |  4  |  5  |    |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1    | 0.6       | 0.3 |           |           |     |     |    | add rax, rcx
|   1    | 0.3       | 0.6 |           |           |     |     | CP | add rcx, 0x1
|   1    | 0.3       | 0.3 |           |           |     | 0.3 | CP | add rbx, rcx
|   1    |           |     |           |           |     | 1.0 | CP | cmp rcx, 0x1000
|   0F   |           |     |           |           |     |     |    | jl 0xffffffffffffffef
```

The more I don't understand why throughput is 1.65.

Comment: did you try running it, and measuring the instructions-per-cycle?  (Change 4096 to something gigantic).  I haven't finished analysing it yet, but your latency of 1+1+1 is obviously wrong: `cmp` is only part of a dependency chain when a later insn reads the flags.

Comment: IACA is *not* cycle-accurate.  It's always an approximation, except in easy cases where the bottleneck is simple.  Its 1.65 is pretty close to the observed number.  Oh I just noticed that 1.65 is from a different loop with an extra `add`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first loop, there are two dep chains, one for `rax` and one for `rcx`.

```
add rax, rcx  # depends on rax and rcx from the previous iteration, produces rax for the next iteration

add rcx, 1    # latency = 1
```

The 2-cycle latency dep chain of `add rcx,1` -> `add rax, rcx` spans 2 iterations (so it already has time to happen) and it's not even loop-carried anyway (because `rax` doesn't feed back into the `add rcx,1`).

In any given iteration, only the previous iteration's results are needed to produce this iteration's results.  There are no loop-carried dependencies within an iteration, only between iterations.

Like I explained [in answer to your question a couple days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36758940/224132), the `cmp/jcc` is not part of the loop-carried dep chain.

`cmp` is only part of a dep chain if a `cmov` or `setcc` reads the flag output it generates.  Control dependencies are predicted, not waited for like data dependencies.

In practice, on my E6600 (first-gen Core2, I don't have a SnB available at the moment):

```
; Linux initializes most registers to zero on process startup, and I'm lazy so I depended on this for this one-off test.  In real code, I'd xor-zero ecx
    global _start
_start:
L1:
    add eax, ecx        ; (1)
    add ecx, 1          ; (2)
    cmp ecx, 0x80000000 ; (3)
    jb L1            ; can fuse with cmp on Core2 (in 32bit mode)

    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80
```

I ported it to 32bit since Core2 can only macro-fuse in 32bit mode, and used a `jb` since Core2 can only macro-fuse unsigned branch conditions.  I used a large loop counter so I didn't need another loop outside this.  (IDK why you picked a tiny loop count like 4096.  Are you sure you weren't measuring extra overhead from something else outside your short loop?)

```
$ yasm -Worphan-labels -gdwarf2 -felf tinyloop.asm && ld -m elf_i386 -o tinyloop tinyloop.o
$ perf stat -e task-clock,cycles,instructions,branches ./tinyloop

Performance counter stats for './tinyloop':

    897.994122      task-clock (msec)         #    0.993 CPUs utilized          
 2,152,571,449      cycles                    #    2.397 GHz                    
 8,591,925,034      instructions              #    3.99  insns per cycle        
 2,147,844,593      branches                  # 2391.825 M/sec                  

   0.904020721 seconds time elapsed
```

So it runs at 3.99 insns per cycle, which means ~one iteration per cycle.

I'd be surprised if your Ivybridge runs that exact code only about half as fast.  Update: per discussion in chat, yes, it appears IVB really does only get 2.14 IPC.  (one iteration per 1.87c).  **Changing the `add rax, rcx` to `add rax, rbx` or something to remove the dependency on the loop counter from the previous iteration brings the throughput up to 3.8 IPC (one iteration per 1.05c).**  I don't understand why this happens.

With a similar loop that doesn't depend on macro-fusion, (`add` / `inc ecx` / `jnz`) I also get one iteration per 1c.  (2.99 insns per cycle).

However, having a 4th insn in the loop that also reads `ecx` makes it massively slower.  Core2 can issue 4 uops per clock, even though (like SnB/IvB) it only has three ALU ports.  (A lot of code include memory uops, so this does make sense.)

```
add eax, ecx       ; changing this to add eax,ebx  helps when there are 4 non-fusing insns in the loop
; add edx, ecx     ; slows us down to 1.34 IPC, or one iter per 3c
; add edx, ebx     ; only slows us to 2.28 IPC, or one iter per 1.75c
                   ; with neither:    3    IPC, or one iter per 1c
inc ecx
jnz L1             # loops 2^32 times, doesn't macro-fuse on Core2
```

I expected to still run at 3 IPC, or one iter per 4/3 = 1.333c.  However, pre-SnB CPUs have many more bottlenecks, like ROB-read and register-read bottlenecks.  SnB's switch to a physical register file eliminated those slowdowns.

---

In your 2nd loop, IDK why it doesn't run at one iteration per 1.333c.  The insn updating `rbx` can't run until after the other instructions from that iteration, but that's what out-of-order execution is for.  Are you sure it's as slow as one iteration per 1.85 cycles?  You measured with `perf` for a high enough count to get meaningful data?  (`rdtsc` cycle counting isn't accurate unless you disable turbo and frequency scaling, but perf counters still count actual core cycles).

I wouldn't expect it to be much different from

```
L1:    
    add rax, rcx
    add rbx, rcx      # before/after inc rcx shouldn't matter because of out-of-order execution
    add rcx, 1
    cmp rcx, 4096
    jl L1
```

Comment: Thanks :), In comment to your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36739118/dependency-chain-analysis/36758940#36758940
you said that there is loop-carried dependency ( I mean that : "add is the loop-carried dependency chain," ) and now you said there there is no.

Comment: @Gilgamesz: My wording was confusing, sorry.  I meant that `cmp`'s dependency on `add` exists, but isn't part of a loop-carried dependency chain.  There are of course loop-carried dependency chains, but the dependencies within each iteration aren't part of them.

Comment: For my first loop I got 1.9 cylce per iteration ( perf and Agner Fog tool) but I cannot understand why 1.9. We have two cycle latency loop-carried `add rax, rcx  # depends on rax and rcx from the previous iteration, produces rax for the next iteration`

Comment: Are you sure your numbers are cycles per iteration, not **instructions per cycle**?  `perf` can't directly measure cycles per iter.  But anyway, *no*, there is not a 2-cycle latency dependency chain between one iteration and the next.  The 2-cycle latency dep chain of `inc rcx` -> `add rax, rcx` is across 2 iterations (so it already has time to happen) and it's not loop-carried (because `rax` doesn't feed back into the  `inc rcx`).

Comment: I got from `perf` : `192380778      cycles                    #    3,207 GHz ` and I divided it by number of iterations 100000000. Perhaps I misunderstand something but I am making progress thanks to you ;)

Comment: @Gilgamesz: Yup, you calculated correctly, but it's probably best to look at insns per cycle from `perf` and then divide the number of insns in the loop by that.  If there's any sampling noise, it will might be similar for cycles and insns.  I added some test results for Core2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110179/discussion-between-gilgamesz-and-peter-cordes).