# SSE code using intrinsics runs about as fast as regular code

Tags: c++, assembly, sse, intrinsics

I wrote some code to test/play around comparing regular C++ code with SSE intrinsics.
What I noticed is that both sections of the code shown below run at similar times, usually with a difference of 5-10%.
Naïvely, I'd expect something more noticeable.

I post the code here.
Below the code, you may find some interesting sections of the disassembled code, which just added to my confusion.

```
// main.cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <immintrin.h>

using cdouble_sse = __m128d;
using cdouble = std::complex<double>;

cdouble_sse prod_sse(cdouble_sse val, cdouble_sse other);
cdouble prod(cdouble a, cdouble b);

int main() {
    int constexpr N = 10000;
    int constexpr N2 = 1000000;

    cdouble *v1 = (cdouble*)_mm_malloc(N*sizeof(cdouble), alignof(cdouble_sse));
    cdouble *v2 = (cdouble*)_mm_malloc(N*sizeof(cdouble), alignof(cdouble_sse));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        v1[i] = cdouble{drand48(), drand48()};
        v2[i] = cdouble{drand48(), drand48()};
    }

    {
        double const div = 1.0 / N;
        cdouble out = 0.0;

        auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        for (int t = 0; t < N2; ++t) {
            cdouble out_tmp = 0.0;
            cdouble *p1 = v1;
            cdouble *p2 = v2;
            cdouble *end = p1 + N;
            for (; p1 != end; ++p1, ++p2)
                out_tmp += prod(*p1, *p2);
            out += out_tmp * div;
        }
        auto end   = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

        std::cout << out.real() << '\t' << out.imag() << '\n';
        std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = end - start;
        std::cout << elapsed.count();
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    {
        cdouble_sse div{1.0 / N, 1.0 / N};
        cdouble_sse out{0.0, 0.0};

        auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        for (int t = 0; t < N2; ++t) {
            cdouble_sse out_tmp{0.0, 0.0};
            cdouble_sse *p1 = reinterpret_cast<cdouble_sse*>(v1);
            cdouble_sse *p2 = reinterpret_cast<cdouble_sse*>(v2);
            cdouble_sse *end = p1 + N;
            for (; p1 != end; ++p1, ++p2) {
                cdouble_sse tmp = prod_sse(*p1, *p2);
                out_tmp = _mm_add_pd(out_tmp, tmp);
            }
            out = _mm_add_pd(out, _mm_mul_pd(out_tmp, div));
        }
        auto end   = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

        cdouble res = cdouble{out[0], out[1]};

        std::cout << res.real() << '\t' << res.imag() << '\n';
        std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = end - start;
        std::cout << elapsed.count();
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    _mm_free(v1);
    _mm_free(v2);

    return 0;
}
```

```
// prods.cpp
cdouble_sse prod_sse(cdouble_sse val, cdouble_sse other) {
        auto const x1 = _mm_shuffle_pd(val, val, 0);
        auto const y1 = _mm_shuffle_pd(val, val, 3);
        auto const y2 = _mm_shuffle_pd(other, other, 1);

        auto const z1 = _mm_mul_pd(y1, y2);

        return cdouble_sse{_mm_fmsubadd_pd(x1, other, z1)};
}

cdouble prod(cdouble a, cdouble b) { return std::conj(a) * b; }
```

```
ARGS=--std=c++20 -march=native -O2

all: main

prods.o: prods.cpp Makefile
    g++ $(ARGS) prods.cpp -c

main: main.cpp prods.o
    g++ $(ARGS) main.cpp -c
    g++ $(ARGS) main.o prods.o -o main
    objdump -Cd main > dump_main
```

Here are the sections from the disassembled code that call the `prod` and `prod_sse` functions:

```
    11c0:   c4 c1 7b 10 07          vmovsd (%r15),%xmm0
    11c5:   c4 c1 7b 10 4f 08       vmovsd 0x8(%r15),%xmm1
    11cb:   c5 fb 10 13             vmovsd (%rbx),%xmm2
    11cf:   c5 fb 10 5b 08          vmovsd 0x8(%rbx),%xmm3
    11d4:   48 83 c3 10             add    $0x10,%rbx
    11d8:   e8 63 03 00 00          call   1540 <prod(std::complex<double>, std::complex<double>)>
    11dd:   c4 e1 f9 6e ed          vmovq  %rbp,%xmm5
    11e2:   c5 d3 58 e0             vaddsd %xmm0,%xmm5,%xmm4
    11e6:   c5 f3 58 34 24          vaddsd (%rsp),%xmm1,%xmm6
    11eb:   49 83 c7 10             add    $0x10,%r15
    11ef:   c4 e1 f9 7e e5          vmovq  %xmm4,%rbp
    11f4:   c5 fb 11 34 24          vmovsd %xmm6,(%rsp)
    11f9:   4c 39 f3                cmp    %r14,%rbx
    11fc:   75 c2                   jne    11c0 <main+0xf0>

...

    12d8:   c4 c1 79 28 0c 1c       vmovapd (%r12,%rbx,1),%xmm1
    12de:   c4 c1 79 28 44 1d 00    vmovapd 0x0(%r13,%rbx,1),%xmm0
    12e5:   48 83 c3 10             add    $0x10,%rbx
    12e9:   e8 32 02 00 00          call   1520 <prod_sse(double __vector(2), double __vector(2))>
    12ee:   c5 f9 58 14 24          vaddpd (%rsp),%xmm0,%xmm2
    12f3:   c5 f9 29 14 24          vmovapd %xmm2,(%rsp)
    12f8:   48 81 fb 00 71 02 00    cmp    $0x27100,%rbx
    12ff:   75 d7                   jne    12d8 <main+0x208>
```

The non-SSE version is using twice as many `mov`'s as the SSE version, which makes sense.
You can also see below the disassembled code for both product functions:

```
0000000000001520 <prod_sse(double __vector(2), double __vector(2))>:
    1520:   c4 e3 79 05 d0 00       vpermilpd $0x0,%xmm0,%xmm2
    1526:   c4 e3 79 05 d9 01       vpermilpd $0x1,%xmm1,%xmm3
    152c:   c4 e3 79 05 c0 03       vpermilpd $0x3,%xmm0,%xmm0
    1532:   c5 f9 59 c3             vmulpd %xmm3,%xmm0,%xmm0
    1536:   c4 e2 e9 b7 c1          vfmsubadd231pd %xmm1,%xmm2,%xmm0
    153b:   c3                      ret    
    153c:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)

0000000000001540 <prod(std::complex<double>, std::complex<double>)>:
    1540:   c5 e3 10 eb             vmovsd %xmm3,%xmm3,%xmm5
    1544:   c5 f1 57 1d d4 0a 00    vxorpd 0xad4(%rip),%xmm1,%xmm3        # 2020 <_IO_stdin_used+0x20>
    154b:   00 
    154c:   c5 eb 10 e2             vmovsd %xmm2,%xmm2,%xmm4
    1550:   c5 fb 10 f0             vmovsd %xmm0,%xmm0,%xmm6
    1554:   c5 fb 59 d5             vmulsd %xmm5,%xmm0,%xmm2
    1558:   c5 e3 59 c5             vmulsd %xmm5,%xmm3,%xmm0
    155c:   c4 e2 e9 9d cc          vfnmadd132sd %xmm4,%xmm2,%xmm1
    1561:   c4 e2 c9 bb c4          vfmsub231sd %xmm4,%xmm6,%xmm0
    1566:   c5 f9 2e c1             vucomisd %xmm1,%xmm0
    156a:   7a 01                   jp     156d <prod(std::complex<double>, std::complex<double>)+0x2d>
    156c:   c3                      ret    
    156d:   50                      push   %rax
    156e:   c5 d3 10 cd             vmovsd %xmm5,%xmm5,%xmm1
    1572:   c5 db 10 c4             vmovsd %xmm4,%xmm4,%xmm0
    1576:   c5 cb 10 d6             vmovsd %xmm6,%xmm6,%xmm2
    157a:   e8 b1 fa ff ff          call   1030 <__muldc3@plt>
    157f:   5a                      pop    %rdx
    1580:   c3                      ret
```

The code for `prod` performs more operations than that of `prod_sse`, since it deals with real and imaginary parts separately.

Can anyone explain to me why the SSE version is only 5-10% faster than the "regular" version?

**Edit:** even if I compile with the `-flto` flag, the time difference between SSE and non-SSE codes is still around 5-10%.

Comment: Don't underestimate what a compiler will do for you. They can take things into account like loop unrolling, reducing branches, pipelining of the CPU etc. So it is not that strange. You might like to watch this [what has my compiler done for me lately](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSkpMdDe4g4) by Matt Godbolt (from compiler explorer)

Comment: Shuffles are low throughput (1/clock on Intel before Ice Lake) but 1c latency for in-lane.  FMAs are 2/clock throughput although higher latency.  If you insist on storing your complex numbers with real and imaginary interleaved, that hurts a lot, especially with only 128-bit vectors.

Comment: It's pretty unfortunate that your compiler isn't inlining `call   prod`.  That makes it store/reload the sum in the loop that calls it, since x86-64 SysV has no call-preserved XMM registers. It's a pretty tiny function, so probably you forgot to make it visible for inlining.  You could use `-flto` to allow cross-file inlining without moving it to a header if you want.  You might still just bottleneck on FP add latency, though, without using multiple accumulators (or letting the compiler vectorize with `-O3 -ffast-math`; clang will tend to unroll with multiple accumulators, unlike GCC)

Comment: See also [Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables? (Unrolling FP loops with multiple accumulators)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45113527) re: FP dep chains and throughput vs. latency.

Comment: This is just a dot product of complex numbers, right, at least in the inner loop?  Looks like the repeat loop is accumulating `out` across outer iterations, but dividing by `N` each time.  That may help stopping a compiler from optimizing away the repeat loop, but the inner loop is still effectively a dot-product.  (But with complex multiply.)

Comment: @PeterCordes That lack of inlining was on purpose. I wanted to see how the functions would perform without any extra unrolling or anything.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I know the compiler can, and does, a lot. I've actually watched that video a while ago already ;) My question here is why the code that the compiler has generated, despite using instructions that act only on *half* of `xmm` registers run as fast as instructions that use the entire register.

Comment: Ok, so you intentionally created a serious latency bottleneck in the caller, with an independent call to `prod`, so you're pretty much only going to slow down if the `prod` implementation takes so much throughput resources that it becomes a worse throughput bottleneck than your 4c (ALU) + 5c (store/reload) latency bottleneck.  Or so many uops that out-of-order exec has trouble overlapping iterations.  The interesting thing is how this function would inline into a loop like this, not individual calls, and you're not even calling in a way that's sensitive to throughput differences.

Comment: If that doesn't make sense to you after seeing the explanation, for necessary background and a more detailed explanation, see my answers on [Latency bounds and throughput bounds for processors for operations that must occur in sequence](//stackoverflow.com/q/63095394), [Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables? (Unrolling FP loops with multiple accumulators)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45113527), and [Why does this code execute more slowly after strength-reducing multiplications to loop-carried additions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72306573).

Comment: Also [How many CPU cycles are needed for each assembly instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/692718) (that's not how timing works, as that answer explains).  And https://agner.org/optimize/ re: how CPU pipelines work.

Comment: Thanks for all the links, and I'll be sure to read them later. But, in summary, what you're saying is that both codes run at roughly the same speed because of memory access latency...? Or what?

Comment: No, because of the dependency chain through `out_tmp += (independent work)`.  That dep chain involves a store/reload (nothing to do with DRAM latency; it's store-forwarding from the store buffer) as well as an `addpd` or 2x `addsd`.  (Depending on your CPU, it might be able to start 2x `addsd` instructions in parallel, e.g. on Skylake and later; you haven't said what CPU model number.)

Comment: The time difference of functions due to alignment of code and date can be 40%. So I would say your measured difference is still below the noise level. You haven't proven there even is a difference in speed yet other than random effects.