# How could I do loop unrolling for this function?

Tags: c++, loops, optimization, micro-optimization

I am trying to do loop unrolling using parallel accumulators but I am confused by the dependencies and calculations. The result and result2 should ideally **run independent of each other** in order to make use of CPU microarchitecture pipelined design, so that they can be executed in parallel. Meaning the following code should not be used:

```
for (i = degree - 1; i >= 1; i-=2)
{
    result = a[i] + x * result;
    result2 = a[i-1] + x * result; //same dependency
}
```

**Original function:**

```
double polyh(double a[], double x, long degree)
{
    long i;
    double result = a[degree];
    for (i = degree - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        result = a[i] + x * result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

INTO:

```
double poly_opt(double a[], double x, long degree)
{
    long i;
    double result = a[degree];
    double result_2 = 0;
    double result_array[2] = {result, result_2};

    double xpwr_1 = x;     // 1
    double xpwr_2 = x * x; // 2
    double xpwr_array[2] = {xpwr_1, xpwr_2};
    for (i = degree - 1; i >= 1; i -= 2)
    {
        result = a[i] + xpwr_1 * result;
        result_2 = a[i - 1] + xpwr_2 * result_2;

        xpwr_1 = xpwr_1 * x * x;
        xpwr_2 = xpwr_2 * x * x;
    }

    // leftover when input not multiple of loop unrolling factor
    for (; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        result = a[i] + xpwr_1 * result;
        xpwr_1 = x * xpwr_1;
    }
    return result * result_2;
}
```

I am trying to introduce a 2nd variable result2 to do a loop unrolling of 2 but I was unable to get the result as the code above does not work.

This was an attempt without using parallel accumulators and loop unrolling factor of 8 which works slightly but I would like introduce new variables in hopes of speeding it up:

```
double poly_opt(double a[], double x, long degree)
{
    long i;
    double result = a[degree];
    for (i = degree - 1; i >= 8; i -= 9)
    {
        result = a[i - 8] + (a[i - 7] + (a[i - 6] + (a[i - 5] + (a[i - 4] + (a[i - 3] + ((a[i - 2] + (a[i - 1] + (a[i] + x * result) * x) * x) * x)) * x) * x) * x) * x) * x;
    }

    // leftover when input not multiple of loop unrolling factor
    for (; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        result = a[i] + x * result;
    }

    return result;
}
```

I am testing with these data sets:

```
double a[] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
double x = 0.5;
long degree = 359;

int main()
{
    std::cout << polyh(a, x, degree) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The correct output should be: 3.1428571429

Comment: "I am trying to introduce a 2nd variable result2 to do a loop unrolling of 2 but I was unable to get the result." Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: with `for (i = degree - 1; i >= 0; i--)` the last iteration is with `i=0`, what does `a[i - 1]` access?

Comment: It's undefined behaviour, but can you just post the code you use, and not fiddle with it?

Comment: Semi-related: [Why does this code execute more slowly after strength-reducing multiplications to loop-carried additions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72306573) for unrolling with multiple dep chains with a non-trivial recurrence.  (evaluating `poly(i+1)` in terms of `poly(i)` instead of independently from scratch, for 2nd-order polynomials.  See my answer for working code).  Also related re: perf analysis of a rolled-up `xpwr` loop: [Latency bounds and throughput bounds for processors for operations that must occur in sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63095394)

Comment: Test with a smaller input, much lower degree like 3 to 4 coefficients, so you can explore the off-by-one cases in the first or second loop iteration when you single-step.  Also, an `x` value like `10.0` might make it easy to see which terms of the polynomial got calculated correctly, with 1-digit coefficients each term will give the value of one decimal digit of the result.  Or maybe x=100 so even if it's wrong, it's maybe not disturbing the neighbouring digits as much.

Comment: What result does it give ?

Comment: Dumb question: Did you profile the code to determine if this is even your biggest slow-down?

Comment: @Casey: The data dependency is the bottleneck for a large polynomial evaluated using Horner's rule (the original `polyh`), especially on a machine without FMA so the critical path latency of the loop-carried dependency chain is `addsd` + `mulsd` latency.  e.g. 8 cycles total on Haswell (like the machine discussed in the CS:APP exercises this code is from, see links in my earlier comment).  During those 8 cycles, it has the throughput to start 8 of each op instead of 1 of each. Estrin's Scheme can create some more ILP (instruction level parallelism) with minor extra overhead vs. OP's strategy.

Comment: `xpwr_2 = xpwr_2 * x * x;` is doomed to inefficiency if you compile with strict FP math (not `-ffast-math`.)  It has to evaluate `(xpwr_2 * x) * x;` due to order of operations; FP math isn't strictly associative due to rounding errors, so the compiler can't optimize it to one multiply with a loop-invariant x^2 unless you write it as `xpwr_2 *= x * x;` or `xpwr_2 = xpwr_2 * (x * x);` if you insist on not using `*=`.  Or since you strongly want this optimization, [CSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination) and hoist that expression yourself with `double x2 = x*x`