# Optimize SIMD Version of Range Generation Algorithm

Tags: c, x86-64, simd, avx

On one of my projects in `C`,  I want to quickly generate one-dimensional vectors of double-precision floating-point numbers with a starting point, an increment value, and an ending point. It is important to me that it must be as fast as possible. I was planning to use `SIMD` intrinsics to optimize it. I've written it in `C` using `SIMD` intrinsic. It works as expected. For example, when I call it like `generate_range_avx(0.0, 0.5, 3.0)`, it generates a vector `[0.0 0.5 1.0 1.5 2. 2.5 3.0]`. However, the `SIMD` version is 2-3 times slower than the naive version.

I am not proficient in `SIMD` instructions or intrinsics. So, my vectorization could be wrong and it is definitely inefficient.

Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>

#include <math.h>
#include <immintrin.h> 

#define CALCELTS(start, increment, end) ((size_t)round(((end) - (start)) / (increment)) + 1)

static size_t align(size_t num, size_t alignment) {
    return (num + alignment - 1) & ~(alignment - 1);
}

typedef struct
{
    double* elts;
    size_t len;
} vector_t;

vector_t generate_range_naive(double start, double increment, double end) {
    // Calculate the unaligned number of elements
    size_t num_elements = CALCELTS(start, increment, end);

    size_t aligned_num_elts = align(num_elements, 4);

    double* data = malloc(sizeof * data * aligned_num_elts);
    if (!data)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory.");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_elements; i++) {
        data[i] = start;
        start += increment;
    }
    data[num_elements - 1] = end;
    return (vector_t) { data, num_elements };
}
vector_t generate_range_avx(double start, double increment, double end) {
    // Calculate the unaligned number of elements
    size_t num_elements = CALCELTS(start, increment, end);

    if (num_elements < 4)
        return generate_range_naive(start, increment, end);

    size_t aligned_num_elts = align(num_elements, 4);

    // Allocate memory for the vector.
    double* data = _mm_malloc(sizeof(*data) * aligned_num_elts, 32);

    if (!data)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory.");
        exit(1);
    } 
    __m256d start_v = _mm256_set1_pd(start);
    __m256d indices_v = _mm256_set_pd(3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    __m256d increment_v = _mm256_set1_pd(increment);
    __m256d x_v = _mm256_add_pd(start_v, _mm256_mul_pd(indices_v, increment_v));
    increment_v = _mm256_mul_pd(increment_v, _mm256_set1_pd(4.0));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < aligned_num_elts; i += 4) {
        _mm256_stream_pd(data + i, x_v);
        x_v = _mm256_add_pd(x_v, increment_v);
    }
    data[num_elements - 1] = end;
    return (vector_t) { data, num_elements };
} 

static void print_range(vector_t vec)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.len; i++)
    {
        printf("%lf ", vec.elts[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // I benchmarked the functions using my simple benchmark library but didn't include it here. 
    // If the need to use it arises, I can attach it too. 
    vector_t vec1 = generate_range_avx(1.0, 0.5, 100.0);
    print_range(vec1);
    vector_t vec2 = generate_range_naive(1.0, 0.5, 100.0);
    print_range(vec2);
    return 0;
}
```

My dev environment is `Windows`/`MSVC` and the target architecture is `x86_64`. Therefore, I have used the compiler intrinsics.

- What is wrong with my code?
- Is it possible to optimize it?
- Or is there no optimized way of such a range generation problem using SIMD?

**Note**: *The language in the question is `C` but you can answer it with `x86_64` assembly codes if you want.*

Comment: How big are your arrays?  They have to be pretty huge for `_mm256_stream_pd` to be worth it, like bigger than L3 cache, or at least you have to not read them again soon.  (Which would raise the question: why generate it now if you're not about to read it. Better to generate on the fly or in small chunks (cache blocking) when needed.)

Comment: The overhead of putting data into simd vectors and then extracting them to an array of doubles probably outweighs the increase in arithmetic performance.

Comment: @PeterCordes They are as big as 200 to 500 elements.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes either.  It's a [mcve] with a fairly clear reason why your version is slower, other than cache-bypassing NT stores.  FP dependency chains: very similar to [Why does this code execute more slowly after strength-reducing multiplications to loop-carried additions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72333152) - unroll with more accumulators to hide addition latency, or redo conversion from integer every iteration.

Comment: Ok that's tiny, absolutely don't use `stream` stores!!

Comment: OK, now should I use `store` or `storeu`?

Comment: Have you tried making an array of __m256d first them memcopying it to your destination?

Comment: No, I didn't. I directly operate on an array of doubles: calculate the next four elements and write it to the dest.

Comment: @PeterCordes I didn't understand *"It's a minimal reproducible example with a fairly clear reason why your version is slower, other than cache-bypassing NT stores."*. Did you mean that it is slow because of cache-bypassing NT stores? I read a fair amount about CPU cache but some points confuse me.

Comment: @SimonGoater: That makes no sense.  `__m256d` isn't magic, an array of `__m256d` isn't cheaper to make than an array of 4x as many `double` elements.  `vec_array[i] = v;` compiles to the same asm as `_mm256_store_pd( &double_array[i*4], v );` (which can depend on how you use that array, e.g. a small fixed-size array of `__m256d` could just get optimized into registers the same as multiple `__m256d` variables, if it's just a local array).  Anyway, the last thing you want is extra copying, just store your vector results where you want them.

Comment: @SimonGoater: Also no, you could get a SIMD speedup with this for sizes of 4 to 8 elements (especially if you can round up the allocation size to a multiple of 32 bytes so you can skip the cleanup).  Scalar FP math is already in the same registers as vectors on most ISAs; on x86-64 they're XMM/YMM.  200 to 500 is plenty large enough to get the expected 4x speedup if the compiler isn't already vectorizing your scalar code.  It might well be since this is a very simple problem.

Comment: @jtxkopt-StandWithPalestine: You're allocating storage for this so you can make it aligned.  In that case you might as well use `store` instead of `storeu`, just to stop some older GCC versions from making a mess.  (*[Why doesn't gcc resolve \_mm256\_loadu\_pd as single vmovupd?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52626726)*).

Comment: @jtxkopt-StandWithPalestine: I said there was a reason **other than** NT stores that this would be slow.  Read the second half of the comment you quoted and the linked answer explaining an FP add dependency chains.  (I just realized that the scalar version is doing `double` increments, so it can't be doing a fresh conversion from integer.  And it could only vectorize if you compiled with /fp:fast, otherwise it has to preserve that sequence of FP operations.  So it must just be the NT stores (`_mm256_stream_pd`) that have to go all the way to DRAM that make it even slower than that.)

Comment: > OK, now should I use `store` or `storeu`? -- `_mm256_stream_pd` already requires aligned storage, and you are indeed ensuring alignment by means of `_mm_malloc`. So you can use `_mm256_store_pd`.

Comment: You don't need the `if (num_elements < 4)` check in the AVX routine as you're aligning the number of elements to 4 anyway.

Comment: Modern microarchitectures have multiple store units (e.g. Ice Lake has two), so you may benefit from unrolling the loop at least 2x.

Comment: Note that `_mm_malloc` requires the memory to be released with `_mm_free`, which is formally (and possibly factually) incompatible with `malloc`/`free` that you use in the scalar code.

Comment: Make sure you're enabling optimization and that the compiler is not generating some stupid code by examining the disassembler. MSVC is especially bad about generating vectorized code. On small arrays the preparation step starts being more significant in addition to the main loop, so pay attention to what the compiler generates for complex intrinsics like `_mm256_set1_pd` and `_mm256_set_pd`.

Comment: I check the condition because I think if the length of the vector is less than 4 items, there is nothing to vectorize so fallback to the scaler code. Am I wrong about it? And why did I use `stream`. I used it because I thought that it can be correct to avoid a cacheline copy. And to be honest, I am not quite sure on when to use it. I am a little bit confused about cache and cacheline optimizations. I am very new to that hardware related topics such as memory internals, cache, so on. I am trying to learn and improve myself on more hwrelated concepts. Thank y'all for your invaluable feedbacks.

Comment: Unless `num_elements < 4` is very common, it's not worth the compare+branch to detect that special case at all.  That extra compare slows down the fast path slightly, and is another branch for the branch predictors.  Also, for the `num_elements == 3` case, one set of vector ops might be as cheap or cheaper than 3 scalar iterations with 3 separate stores.  Or at least not much worse despite all the setup.

Comment: If you do decide to keep a special case for very small counts, make sure to fix it to use `_mm_malloc` instead of `malloc`.  (Or replace `_mm_malloc` with `aligned_alloc` or `posix_memalign` or another allocator compatible with `mallc`/`free`; See [How to solve the 32-byte-alignment issue for AVX load/store operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32612190).)  You could let it align less for the smaller allocations, but then other uses of these arrays can't assume they're aligned by 32 and contain at least one full vector of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following version. Same idea as your implementation, two changes.

1. Replaced `_mm256_stream_pd` with regular vector stores.
2. Unrolled the loop by 4. I think your version might bottleneck on the latency of `_mm256_add_pd` instruction. According to [uops.info](https://www.uops.info/table.html), on most modern processors that latency is 3-4 clock cycles. This means no matter what else is in the loop, your original loop throttles to 3-4 cycles/iteration due to the continuous data dependency chain. My loop also does that, for the same reason, however 1 iteration of my loop generates 16 numbers, as opposed to 4 numbers in your version.

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <math.h>

struct vector_t
{
    double* elts;
    size_t len;
};

size_t computeCount( double start, double increment, double end )
{
    double len = end - start;
    len /= increment;
    long num = lround( ceil( len ) );
    return (size_t)num;
}

struct vector_t generateRange( double start, double increment, double end )
{
    size_t lenExact = computeCount( start, increment, end );
    size_t lenAligned = ( lenExact + 15 ) & ( ~(size_t)15 );

    double* rdi = (double*)_mm_malloc( lenAligned * sizeof( double ), 32 );

    struct vector_t result;
    result.len = lenExact;
    result.elts = rdi;

    __m256d vIndices = _mm256_set_pd( 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
    __m256d vInc1 = _mm256_set1_pd( increment );
    vIndices = _mm256_mul_pd( vIndices, vInc1 );

    __m256d v0 = _mm256_set1_pd( start );
    v0 = _mm256_add_pd( v0, vIndices );

    __m256d vInc4 = _mm256_mul_pd( vInc1, _mm256_set1_pd( 4 ) );
    __m256d v1 = _mm256_add_pd( v0, vInc4 );
    __m256d vInc8 = _mm256_add_pd( vInc4, vInc4 );
    __m256d v2 = _mm256_add_pd( v0, vInc8 );
    __m256d v3 = _mm256_add_pd( v2, vInc4 );
    __m256d vInc = _mm256_add_pd( vInc8, vInc8 );

    double* endPointer = rdi + lenAligned;
    for( ; rdi < endPointer; rdi += 16 )
    {
        _mm256_store_pd( rdi, v0 );
        _mm256_store_pd( rdi + 4, v1 );
        _mm256_store_pd( rdi + 8, v2 );
        _mm256_store_pd( rdi + 12, v3 );

        v0 = _mm256_add_pd( v0, vInc );
        v1 = _mm256_add_pd( v1, vInc );
        v2 = _mm256_add_pd( v2, vInc );
        v3 = _mm256_add_pd( v3, vInc );
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: The OP's typical array size is at most 200 to 500 elements.  If they don't call this very frequently, or if even smaller sizes are common, they might want to only unroll by 2 to keep code-size smaller and simplify startup/cleanup.  Out-of-order exec can keep working on later iterations while finding new independent work after the loop to keep other execution units busy.  But yes, an unroll of 4 is very reasonable in general, especially if you still don't mind rounding your allocation sizes up to a multiple of 16 elements instead of just 4.

Comment: Hey, const! I've read your SIMD blog post before. Yeah, your version is faster than mine. The difference is close to 2x-3x depending on the vector size, especially when the vector size becomes smaller. When the vector size becomes larger and larger, it outperforms the scaler code.

Comment: I forgot to ask. Is the benefit of unrolling to reduce latency by taking advantage of OoO execution or something else?

Comment: @jtxkopt-StandWithPalestine Yeah, it’s OO execution. Processors submit multiple instructions per cycle. After the processor submits that `vaddpd`, the result becomes available after 3-4 cycles, see latency numbers on uops.info. My unrolled version submits 4 of these `vaddpd`, and they don’t have data dependencies between them because they increment 4 different values, they will run in parallel. Your version has a single `vaddpd` in the loop. A next iteration of the loop needs to wait for the previous value to become available once the `vaddpd` on the previous iteration delivers the result.